# Abrir arquivo .txt como tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou querendo adicionar ao meu código um **"HELP"**, tipo caso ele clique na palavra ele abra um **pop-up** mostrando os detalhes dos campos. Mas eu gostaria de fazer isso com um arquivo **.txt** ... Onde abra uma **pop-up** contendo o texto do **.txt**! Eu fiz isso em **tooltip** que abre um pequeno balão contendo umas informações:

```css
<style> .tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 26px;
  z-index: 98;
  color: #fff;
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 99;
}
</style>
```

```html
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <font face="arial" color="blue" size="-1">Senha do Usuário :</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" align="left" name="tx_senh_usua" size="7" value="SEDS" readonly="true">
    <span style="color: blue;" data-title="Senha padrão para novos usuários." class="tooltip">?</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Tem como chamar um arquivo **.txt** ao selecionar ou quando clicar da mesma forma?

Comment: O conteudo do `.txt` dentro do tooltip? ou tem que ser uma popup mesmo?

Comment: Teria que ser uma popup, mas não como um alert e-e' Eu mostrei um exemplo com o tooltip, porque é um exemplo mais "chamativo".

Comment: Você vai ter que ler esse TXT de alguma forma, não vai dar pra fazer só via HTML e CSS

Comment: Qual linguagem está usando no backend?

Comment: Sim @KhaosDoctor, tenho em mente que terei de utilizar JS ou alguma outra linguagem para ler o .txt, mas não sei como fazer que apareça como uma pop-up esse arquivo .txt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom para ler um arquivo `.txt` necessita de uma linguagem `backend`(roda no lado servidor). Abaixo um exemplo seria utilizando **PHP** que é a forma mais fácil e rápida:

```
<?php
    $txt = file_get_contents("arquivo.txt");
?>
<span style="color: blue;" data-title="<?php echo $txt ?>" class="tooltip">?</span>
```

Comment: Isso sim me ajudou muito @AntonyAlkmim! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um ficheiro tem de fazer do lado do servidor, PHP no seu caso.

Para abrir o ficheiro pode usar o [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) e para ler linha a linha pode usar o [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

```
$ficheiro = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
$texto = array();
if ($ficheiro) {
    while (($linha = fgets($ficheiro)) !== false) {
        // aqui pode trabalhar com o conteúdo da linha
        // no exemplo crio uma array com o conteudo da linha
        $chave_valor = explode("~>", $linha);
        $texto[$chave_valor[0]] = $chave_valor[1];
    }
} else {
    // caso dê erro
} 
fclose($ficheiro);

// e agora pode exportar esse conteudo para o JavaScript
echo json_encode($texto);
```

Comment: O $texto no caso vai conter o que está no conteúdo do .txt né?

Comment: E para abrir ele conforme o focus ele muda a tooltip?

Comment: @Alexandre "$texto no caso vai conter o que está no conteúdo" => sim. Vou atualizar a outra resposta daqui a pouco para continuar a ideia aqui.

Comment: está ok @Sergio, retirou bem minha duvida!