# Como alternar mensagem de txt conforme o focus do campo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Nessa pergunta eu vi como ler o **.txt** ~> [Ler txt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42996/abrir-arquivo-txt-como-tooltip)

Agora quero saber: Caso eu deixe um campo em **focus**, e for sobre a mensagem de **tooltip**, ele deve mostrar uma mensagem referente a aquele campo.

**Ex:** Caso eu deixe o **campo senha** com **focus** e passar por cima do **"?"** do **tooltip** ele deve mostrar uma mensagem referente ao **campo senha**. E caso deixar o **campo nome** com **focus**, mostrar uma mensagem referente a ele.

```css
<style> .tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 26px;
  z-index: 98;
  color: #fff;
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 99;
}
</style>
```

```html
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <font face="arial" color="blue" size="-1">Senha do Usuário :</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" align="left" name="tx_senh_usua" size="7" value="SEDS" readonly="true">
  <td align="right">
    <font face="arial" color="blue" size="-1">Nome :</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" align="left" name="tx_nome_usua" size="7" value="" readonly="true">   
    </td>
    <td>
    <span style="color: blue;" data-title="Senha padrão para novos usuários." class="tooltip">?</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Simplificando ... Eu quero criar um arquivo contendo mensagens para diversos campos. E caso o campo estiver em **focus** e for selecionado o **"?"** de **tooltip**, ele deve verificar nesse arquivo qual a mensagem para o determinado campo!

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Sorry, acabei editando rápido e coloquei o PHP junto!

Comment: Consegues deixar algum campo com _focus_ se eles forem _readonly_?

Comment: O campo com readonly foi somente um exemplo do arquivo com uma mensagem!

Comment: Pra imprimir o texto .txt no tooltip você ja sabe, agora é só criar um tooltip pra ele. ao invés de `.tooltip:hover`, use `.tooltip:focus`.

Comment: Mas ai como irei saber qual a mensagem que tem que mostrar referente a aquele focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso precisa usar JavaScript para mudar o conteudo do Tooltip.

Uma sugestão é usar também um campo `data-` nos inputs que têm focus e ir buscar essa string para dentro do tooltip. No exemplo em baixo mudei também as classes um pouco para poder remover o `tooltip` caso não haja focus.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" data-title="Senha padrão para novos usuários." align="left" name="tx_senh_usua" size="7" value="SEDS">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('.tltp').onmouseover = function () {
    if (document.body == document.activeElement) return this.classList.remove('tooltip');
    var texto = document.activeElement.getAttribute("data-title");
    if (texto) {
        this.setAttribute("data-title", document.activeElement.getAttribute("data-title"));
        this.classList.add('tooltip');
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q34zd30s/

Podia criar uma array no JS com essas tooltips e compilar diretamente do PHP para JS.

---

Seguindo [a ideia que apresentei na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43552/129) vai receber do PHP algo como:

`'{"tx_senh_usua":"Senha do Usu\u00e1rio :","tx_nome_usua":"Nome :"}'`

Assim pode compilar no lado do cliente:

```
var json = JSON.parse(<a string do servidor>);
```

Para ir buscar esta info no tooltip pode fazer assim:

```
var texto = json[document.activeElement.name]; 
this.setAttribute("data-title", texto);
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9s3ck057/

Comment: Então @Sergio, ele irá mostrar caso o campo estiver em focus. Mas tem como fazer com que em vez de pegar o data-title do próprio input, pegar de um arquivo .txt?  **Seguindo a resposta que o Antony Alkmim deu na outra pergunta!

Comment: @Alexandre indiretamente sim. Ou manda o pedido por ajax e faz isso no PHP e devolve para o AJAX, ou faz um echo no PHP para uma array de JavaScript (que compila com a página) e usa daí. Qual prefere?

Comment: Seria mais fácil para o meu problema o echo do PHP para um array de JS!

Comment: @Alexandre e sabe como fazer isso? ou quer que junte mais algo à resposta?

Comment: Me desculpe @Sergio, mas não tenho idéia de como fazer e-e'
 Se puder dar uma luz eu agradeço!

Comment: @Alexandre dá para colocar um exemplo de como o ficheiro .txt está? poderia colocar lá um JSON?

Comment: no ficheiro eu coloquei o campo setando o texto que deve aparecer (pois achei que assim teria como mostrar a mensagem).
`Nome ~> Informe o nome de usuário 
RG ~> Informe o RG do usuário
Telefone ~> Informe o Telefone do usuário
Senha ~> Senha padrão para novos usuários`

Comment: @Alexandre ok, e separado por linhas? e essa chave, qual é a relação com o HTML? quantas chaves/campos tem?

Comment: são separados por linhas, quanto essa chave que coloquei, era só para setar de qual campo ela vem. E atualmente são somente esses campos!

Comment: @Alexandre editei a resposta e juntei a ideia da outra resposta. Diga se consegue pôr a funcionar.

Comment: Eu implementei o que você passou! Mas não chegou a funcionar ... Mesmo assim obrigado @Sergio

Comment: @Alexandre que parte não funcionou?

Comment: Esse trecho `var json = JSON.parse($texto);`
que vem do `<?php json_encode($texto);?>`

Comment: Alexandre: dá um salto aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19388/discussion-between-sergio-and-alexandre

Comment: @Alexandre dá um salto aqui ao chat para te ajudar: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19433/sala-de-encontro